# Why is my xml doc file always getting locked?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

When building an F# project through Visual Studio 2010 (either Build or Rebuild, or Clean -> Build) where I've checked "XML Documentation file" and specified a location in the Build tab of the properties page, I frequently but sporadically run into build failures:

```
FSC: error FS0193: Access to the path 'xxx.XML' is denied.
```

I've experience this with several F# projects / solutions. Most of the time I then just turn it off, but I recently noticed then documentation isn't built into the compiled assemblies (I apparently falsely assumed that the XML doc was only for possible external processing and that the doc comments would always get built in).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know we fixed this bug in VS2010 for F#.  I seem to recall that C# and VB had the bug as well (dunno if they fixed it, I can investigate).  Do you have a C# or VB project referencing the F# project?  (Are you building the solution, or a specific project?)

Comment: As a note to myself in case I forget later, our fix involved a call to the crazy method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivstrackprojectdocumentsevents3.handsofffiles.aspx

Comment: Hi Brian, glad to know it's not just me. I've experience this problem with all combinations: building F# multi-project solution, building mixed C# / F# multi-project solutions (with C# project referencing F# project), building specific F# project only within a solution (but I think it only failed in that case after it already failed trying to build the whole solution first, so building the solution could be the culprit). Was this supposed to be fixed in the first final release of VS2010, or not until SP1 (which I haven't installed yet)?

Comment: It should be fixed in VS2010, let me get back to you.

Comment: @Brian did you find out if this was fixed in VS2010?  I've had similar problems in the past as well.

Comment: @Brian We're using VS2010 Pro and we're having this same issue: when the developer tries to update some external assemblies (and PDB's and XML doc files) the process blows up and they have to close the solution (quit VS) to perform the update.  This is all with C#, by the way.

Comment: @Brian Oh, can that crazy method be used in a command-line utility to release locks on certain files, or can it only be used from inside VS?  Sorry, I have no experience with C++, but now's a great time to start! :)

Comment: This is still a bug in VS 2012, and VS 2013. It's infuriating. Currently restarting VS something like 40 times a day.

Comment: @Brian Looking over the fix at https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fac44095a8dbc7303efa9866e0e2d9dddbdeae5d/vsintegration/src/vs/FsPkgs/FSharp.Project/Common.Source.CSharp/Project/ProjectConfig.cs#L1877-L1896 - Am I correct in assuming this will only fix building from VS, and the issue is still there when building from command line?